# Cambridge IELTS 13 General Training's answer looks incorrect

Tags: meaning, should, ielts, cambridge-exams, answers

[image]

Hi guys,

I am doing IELTS 13 - Test 3 - Reading. The question #2 says "An ability to read music is essential". My answer is "false". The correct answer given by the book is "true". I think the book's answer is incorrect because the 2nd paragraph states "Pariticipants should have basic music reading skills". Based on [RFC2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt), "Should" is not "must", meaning it doesn't require the thing. Meanwhile, "essential" means necessary or needed, it's more likely so important that one can't live without. As I understand, "should" in that context means whether you have music reading skills does not matter.

Am I correct?

Comment: You wouldn't get very far in attempting to play in an orchestra if you couldn't read music at all!  _Should_ is 'used to indicate obligation, duty, or correctness' (Oxford).

Comment: What Kate is saying is that one sense of 'should' is synonymous with 'need to' / 'must'. And that's the one used here. This [obligation] sense of 'should' can be found in all decent dictionaries.

Comment: Two sentences later, they say "It is recommended that you have studied your instrument for at least one year." Contrast this sentence (where it sounds to me like they might be willing to make exceptions) with the sentence containing "should" (where it sounds to me like they are not).

Comment: The real question for a prospective member is what level of music-reading skill is required. There are people who would not regard having "basic music reading skills" as being able to read music. Having basic reading skills might be taken as being able to identify the letters of the alphabet, which doesn't mean you can read. I think the question is a poor one.

Comment: If ***should*** in the cited context was intended to imply ***if possible*** rather than ***of necessity***, they'd have included additional text to make that clear. By well-established convention, job descriptions and similar contexts achieve this by including the word ***ideally*** somewhere in the sentence containing the word ***should***.

Comment: Someone has to say it: A violin player must read sheet music. It's a waste of time to say the test was wrong, rather than learn from what the hell they want. Finding one definition of 'should' as *strongly suggested* not *must* does not eliminate the meaning of *must*. Then, there's the Brit politeness of 'should' that means "After we strongly suggest something that you don't accommodate, we should likely find ourselves not accommodating you, either."

Comment: I've looked up the word "should" in my Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary 8th edition and there is not that meaning of "obligation". I think "should" shouldn't refer to "essential" because "essential" is often used for something extremely important such as "Water is essential for living things." (Cambridge). From my point of view, I don't think the book's answer is correct. Maybe I will try to adapt with how the author of the book thinks to get a better score.

Comment: [should modal verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should) (DUTY)
used to express that it is necessary, desirable, or important to perform the action of the following verb:
-*He should have told me about the change in plans.* 
-*People like that should go to jail.*
-*Where should we meet tonight?*

Comment: This is one of the many ways that *should* is used by native English speakers. The book's answer is correct; your Learner's Dictionary is incomplete.